# In a kubernetes cluster, if I connect to a port of a given Pod ip address, which container inside the Pod am I connecting to?

Tags: kubernetes

Say a pod has two containers, A and B, exposing 80 and 443 respectively. If another pod connects to this pod using its IP address at port 80, how does kubernetes know I'm connecting to container A, not B? And what mechanism does kubernetes employ to guarantee that container A receives my connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All containers in the Pod share the same Network namespace[1]. Only one container will be able to bind a service to given port - so by choosing a port you are picking the target container.

[1] Linux kernel namespace, not to be confused with Kubernetes namespaces.

Comment: Just to supplement, I found the documentation here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#the-kubernetes-network-model